# Eclipse with old Sun USB Keyboard

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, key-bindings, sun

I'm forced to work with Eclipse (3.6) now, and i would like to re-use my favorite Sun keyboard with the left function block for cut/copy/paste/undo/find/etc (can't code without it ..).

So far i got it working with about every IDE/Editor i used, but NOT with eclipse. The keybinding manager simply ignores these keys.

Any hints? Has anybody got it working? I thought it might be related to Java, but i have other Java tools that work (freemind, for example).

Thanks,

Felix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a workaround by installing "autokey" and defining some rules that send -C/V/X/Y/Z to the eclipse window.

But i'm still curious why Eclipse ignores these keycodes/keysyms, especially since autokey needs to be started now (and sometimes crashes).